# How to transpose a matrix without using another matrix?

Tags: arrays, c

> Write a program which will accept 2-dimensional square matrix and find out the transpose of it.
> Program should not make use of another matrix

Hi I am trying to transpose a 2*2 matrix without using another matrix.
Is there anything wrong with my transpose logic?
I am a newbie

```
#include <stdio.h>
    
int main()
{
    int mat[2][2];
    int i, j, temp;
    for (i = 0; i < 2; i++) {
        printf("\nEnter elements of %d row of first matrix: ", i + 1); //i+1 so that it can print 1 row, 2 row, 3 row etc
        for (j = 0; j < 2; j++) { //loop inside to loop to get value for a[0][0],a[0][1],a[0][2]
            scanf("%d", &mat[i][j]);
        }
    }

    printf("The matrix\n");
    for (i = 0; i < 2; i++) {
        for (j = 0; j < 2; j++) {
            printf("%d\t", mat[i][j]);
        }
        printf("\n");
    }

    //transpose logic using same matrix
    for (i = 0; i < 2; i++) {
        for (j = 0; j < 2; j++) {
            temp = mat[i][j];
            mat[i][j] = mat[j][i];
            mat[j][i] = temp;
        }
    }

    printf("The transpose of the matrix is\n");
    for (i = 0; i < 2; i++) {
        for (j = 0; j < 2; j++) {
            printf("%d\t", mat[i][j]);
        }
        printf("\n");
    }
}
```

**EDIT:** I found an easier way to do it however I still don't understand why my transpose logic by using this

```
temp = mat[i][j];
mat[i][j] = mat[j][i];
mat[j][i] = temp;
```

cannot get it to transpose.

Below is my corrected answer

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main()
{
    int mat[2][2];
    int i, j, temp;
    for (i = 0; i < 2; i++) {
        printf("\nEnter elements of %d row of first matrix: ", i + 1);//i+1 so that it can print 1 row, 2 row, 3 row etc
        for (j = 0; j < 2; j++) {//loop inside to loop to get value for a[0][0],a[0][1],a[0][2]
            scanf("%d", &mat[i][j]);
        }
    }

    printf("The matrix\n");
    for (i = 0; i < 2; i++) {
        for (j = 0; j < 2; j++) {
            printf("%d\t", mat[i][j]);
        }
        printf("\n");
    }
    printf("The transpose of the matrix is\n");
    for (i = 0; i < 2; i++) {
        for (j = 0; j < 2; j++) {
            printf("%d\t", mat[j][i]);
        }
        printf("\n");
    }
}
```

Comment: Have you tried it?  It looks like you swap every cell twice.

Comment: `Transpose` is a $100 term for swapping a[0][1] with a[1][0], don't you think?

Comment: Now, with the addition, the question becomes, did you want to transpose _in situ_, or merely output the array in "transposed" sequence?

Answer (score 0):

Your program is a good attempt, but transposing the matrix is like reversing an array: you must stop half way to avoid swapping the transposed values twice, leading to the original matrix as you observe.

You should stop the inner loop when `j == i`, hence change the inner loop to:

```
    for (j = 0; j < i; j++) {   // j < i instead of j < 2
```

Here is a modified version:

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main() {
    int mat[2][2];
    int i, j, temp;

    for (i = 0; i < 2; i++) {
        printf("\nEnter elements of %d row of first matrix: ", i + 1);
        for (j = 0; j < 2; j++) {
            if (scanf("%d", &mat[i][j]) != 1)
                return 1;
        }
    }

    printf("The matrix:\n");
    for (i = 0; i < 2; i++) {
        for (j = 0; j < 2; j++) {
            printf("%d\t", mat[i][j]);
        }
        printf("\n");
    }

    //transpose logic using same matrix
    for (i = 0; i < 2; i++) {
        for (j = 0; j < i; j++) {
            temp = mat[i][j];
            mat[i][j] = mat[j][i];
            mat[j][i] = temp;
        }
    }

    printf("The transpose of the matrix is:\n");
    for (i = 0; i < 2; i++) {
        for (j = 0; j < 2; j++) {
            printf("%d\t", mat[i][j]);
        }
        printf("\n");
    }
    return 0;
}
```

Your *corrected* answer does not transpose the matrix at all, it merely outputs the transposed matrix. The matrix `mat` in memory is unchanged.